# Difference between node = node->next vs *node = *(node->next)?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

What is the difference between these two lines of C code?

```
node = node->next; 
*node = *(node->next);
```

`node` is a linked list Node struct which is defined as following:

```
struct Node{
     int data;
     Node* next;
};

Node* node;
```

Comment: The code you’ve posted isn’t valid C (but it is valid C++). Are you maybe using C++ instead of C?

Comment: I guess `node` is pointer to `Node` structure, i.e. `Node * node;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first code snippet, `node = node->next;`, is a *pointer* assignment. That is, the address value that is currently in `node` will be replaced with the address that is in `node->next`.

The second snippet, `*node = *(node->next);`, *dereferences* the pointers, and copies the *actual data* of the structure that the RHS points to into the structure that the LHS points to. This will be equivalent to the following:

```c
node->data = node->next->data;
node->next = node->next->next;
```

Note: In this second case, the address that `node` contains does not change; that is, it still points to the same location in memory, but the contents of that memory will be changed. In the first case, `node` will point to a different (probably) memory location, and the contents of the old location will be left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

```
node = node->next;
```

You assign pointer to pointer.

```
*node = *(node->next);
```

It's dereference of pointer. It assigns value of `node` to value of next node `node->next`.

Look at the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pointer vs values.  The first one you assign the `node` pointer to the pointer at `node->next`.  The second one you dereference the value of `*(node->next)`, meaning you take its value, and assign it to the value at node.